# If $T:V\to W$ is an injective linear map, show there is a linear map $L:W\to V$ such that $LT=1_V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation. Suppose that $T$ is one-to-one. Show that there is a linear transformation $L:W\to V$ such that $LT=1_V$.

So far I have: 
Since $T$ is injective, then a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ for $V$ gets sent to a linearly independent set $\{T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)\}$ of $W$. I'm not sure how to expand the basis for $W$.

Is it just $B_W=\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$?

I know that if $T$ is 1-1, then $\dim V\leq\dim W$. So $n\leq\dim W$.

Any help from here would be great.

Comment: Hint 1: If you have a linearly independent set of vectors, you can add more vectors to that set to get a basis.


Hint 2: If you want to define a linear transformation (L, in this case), it is enough to say where it sends each basis vector.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: If you need clarification please edit or comment on your question instead of starting a new one.

Comment: we can define L:W->V. For any w in the image of T, so there is a v in V with T(v)=w. We can define L(w)=v. The transformation T is one-to-one so v is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a different solution than most would expect. As $T$ is injective we know that $T^T T$ is a quadratic Matrix with full rank, so it is invertible. Now define
$$L=(T^T T)^{-1} T^T.$$
Than $LT=(T^T T)^{-1} T^T T=I_V$